# Why does "sbt assembly" fail with ResolveException for stax-api.jar?

Tags: windows-7, sbt, apache-spark

While running `sbt assembly`, the command runs for some time and throws the following error on Windows 7:

```
[warn] Strategy 'discard' was applied to 4 files
[warn] Strategy 'first' was applied to 199 files
[info] Assembly up to date: C:\spark_\spark-1.0.2\assembly\target\scala-2.10\spark-assembly-1.0.2-hadoop1.0.4.jar
sbt.ResolveException: download failed: javax.xml.stream#stax-api;1.0-2!stax-api.jar
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:217)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:126)
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: I'm curious where you found out that to install Apache Spark on Windows you need to execute `sbt/sbt assembly`?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski i have edited my question to just use sbt assembly . I installed sbt in windows and then executed the above command. It runs for a while and then throws the above error.

Comment: @samthebest : i was able to run spark in linux without issues. But the problem was that the sbt builds were taking a lot of time compared to windows, lazy to debug the reason, i that thought i would stick onto windows for just to play around with spark.

Comment: Tip: use `sbt compile` and `sbt test` to avoid a full `assembly`.  Yes `sbt` can be a real pain and take eternity to build, I've never bothered trying to debug it either because build tools are usually the spawn of Satan. When I need to do a full build, I just check my email, or find some tabs that need closing, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

running sbt clean before sbt assembly solved the above problem.

Comment: I'll also note that in general you should be using Maven to build Spark.

Comment: @SeanOwen Would you please explain why maven should be used? Just to understand.

Comment: Maven replaced SBT as the build of reference used to create releases, so it's better if you are trying to build your own release.

Answer (score 1):

[In the official documentation of Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/) there's the section **Downloading** that says:

> If you’d like to build Spark from scratch, visit [building Spark with Maven](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-with-maven.html).

where you can find the command that worked fine for me (just two days ago on Mac OS X with Java 8):

```
mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.4.0 -DskipTests clean package
```

p.s. I wish they'd sticked to sbt as the build tool for official releases, though.